# SQL - Insert rows from one table to another when a condition is satisfied

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, insert

What's wrong in this code:

```
INSERT INTO main.table_1 
   (SELECT * 
    FROM TempDatabase.table_1 
    WHERE TempDatabase.table_1.ID != "5855CA0F8E23")
```

I made a condition on ID to prevent duplicates (and also because I applied a constrain on main.table_1). However, as I run in SQLiteManager, I got a syntax error "near SELECT".

If I removed the brackets, still I got another error due to violating constrain on main.table_1 (as If the WHERE condition is totally ignored!)

What am I doing wrong over here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax is your second try, without the parentheses.  (Parentheses are used to define the column names that you will insert into.)

You are getting a constraint violation because, despite what you think, inserting your temp data into your main database is actually violating some constraint on your main db table, even if you exclude the one record that has the id `5855CA0F8E23`.  Check your constraints.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `IGNORE` or `REPLACE` (http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html)

If a constraint violation occurs the rows will be skipped, and it will continue:

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO main.table_1 SELECT * from TempDatabase.table_1
```

If a constraint violation occurs the record in `main.table_1` will be deleted and the full row from `TempDatabase.table_1` will be inserted:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO main.table_1 SELECT * from TempDatabase.table_1
```

There is no method to "merge rows" - that is to aggregate data from both tabs into new rows.

Comment: Yes, this will solve this issue. bfares's answer is also correct, and I fixed the issue by using your syntax. So I checked his answer as "an answer" and your answer has +1 :)